# Error in clusplot function

Tags: r

I am playing with cluster analysis in R and I would like to plot the cluster:

```
teste<-data.frame(v1=rnorm(100),v2=rexp(100),v3=runif(100) )

fit.c<- kmeans(teste,2)
aggregate(teste,by=list(fit.c$cluster),FUN=mean)

clusplot(teste, fit.c$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE,labels=2, lines=0)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Error in clusplot.default(teste, fit.c$cluster, color = TRUE, shade = TRUE,     : 
4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
```

Does anyone know what is happening?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code and got no problems. I am guessing that there is a version mismatch between your R and the packages you are using. Can you make sure that your cluster package is up to date (and any other packages you are using for that matter), and/or update to the latest version of R?

If that doesn't work, can you add the `sessionInfo()` information? That is often helpful for diagnosing these sorts of problems.

Comment: Thanks! I was using an older version of R.